# Javascript parse a string with commas

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this string from my api call:

```
"{'attachments': [{'type': 'html', 'html': 'text-test'}, {'type': 'album', 'album': [{'url': 'htps://s3.eu-central-8f7ba8d118dbf1/pic/cdyegkwkaije7720e2f72.jpg', 'type': 'image'}]}]}"
```

I need to find a way to parse it and be able to iterate over the items in `attachments` list, but when I try to run `JSON.parse(str)` I am getting an error, I guess because the word `attachments` has commas around it.

The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse`

How can I decode it to be able to reach the attachments?

Comment: well JSON requires `"` and all your properties and values use `'` so your api is returning invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to replace ' with " . try this

```
var jsonStr ="{'attachments': [{'type': ..." //your api string

jsonStr = jsonStr.replaceAll("'","\"");
var result = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON requires `"`, not `'`. If this is your own API, you should change the implementation to return `"` quotations. Best to use `JSON.stringify(objectDataToSend)` if your API is written in JavaScript.

If this is not your own API, I'd suggest using the `String.replaceAll()` function  to replace all `'` with `"`:

```
let data = "{'attachments': [{'type': 'html', 'html': 'text-test'}, {'type': 'album', 'album': [{'url': 'htps://s3.eu-central-8f7ba8d118dbf1/pic/cdyegkwkaije7720e2f72.jpg', 'type': 'image'}]}]}"

const result = JSON.parse(data.replaceAll("'", '"'));
```